# How to setup Windows Subsystem Linux (WSL 2) with VSCodium on Windows 10

Tags: linux, windows, terminal, wsl-2, vscodium

So I am using Ubuntu Linux terminal(also have Debian) in windows 10. according to this site:

https://medium.com/nerd-for-tech/how-to-setup-windows-subsystem-linux-with-visual-studio-code-on-windows-10-b06fdbe9b30b

you need Remote - WSL extention to connect with VScode, I am using VSCodium.
So my question is can I install Remote - WSL extention on VSCodium.
Or are there any alternatives to configure it without this extension.I saw on VSCodium market and there is no Remote - WSL.

My purpose is with Ubuntu or Debian terminal to create folders and files such html,css,js.
I can do all this by entering in desktop environment :

`cd /mnt/c/Users/<username>/Desktop`

and also can use this commands:

```
    pwd
    cd 
    cd ..
    clear
    cd /
    cd ~
    mkdir 
    touch 
    mv
```

My problem is that I can not open created folder or any app(including VSCodium), for example open existing folder using this command:

`open . or open index.html`

this commands are not working.can you help with that?
how can I open created folder,file or app using terminal.
Is there any extension to connect VSCodium to my WSL2 and do all commands above?

Comment: Which VSCodium distribution are you using?  Windows or Linux (under WSL)?

Comment: I use Windows 10 under WSL2 , Ubuntu terminal

Comment: Yes, but VSCodium binaries are available for both Linux and Windows.  I'm assuming that you are running the *Windows* binary of VSCodium, right?

Comment: Yes I am running Windows binary of VSCodium.exe

Answer (score 3):

You cannot legally use any of the MS "Remote" extensions as they are closed source and cannot legally be installed on anything other than Microsoft Visual Studio Code, [as per the license](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items/ms-vscode-remote.remote-wsl/license).

AFAIK there is no open source alternative yet.

Comment: Agreed.  Ironically, I came across a related [Hacker News post](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=31713625) today that reminded me of this question from a few weeks back.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds I actually found this question after reading that blog post lol

Answer (score 1):

Lack of a well supported remote extension within VSCodium is very inconvenient. I wanted to develop some Go code *(other languages may have different requirements)*. There are currently a few options that I tried:

### **1. Leave the code in Windows**

WSL mounts the Windows drives, so your editor running in Windows can change the local files and Linux will pick the changes up.

**Pros:**

- Still editing files locally
- Intellisense will work **as long as all tooling is installed on Windows** *(for me, Go tools also had to be installed in Windows in addition to WSL)*

**Cons:**

- No file watcher support *(inotify doesn't work)* = manual recompilation
- Slower builds / file access / Docker access

### **2. Mess with the extension itself**

With a few tweaks it's pretty simple to get the VSCode extension running, see: https://github.com/VSCodium/vscodium/issues/1265

**Pros:**

- Works as well as in VSCode
- Can store files fully within Linux to get proper file watching support

**Cons:**

- Breaks with **any** updates (*extension / IDE - nothing I tried prevented this despite others having success)*
- Intellisense didn't work for me in Go at all *(despite tools being installed in both Linux and Windows)*

### **3. Launch Codium from within WSL *(WSLg)***

This is what I have ended up using because not being able to see errors in my IDE was too annoying *(this is most likely a Go thing though and was no issue for JS when tested)*.

- Launch WSL
- Install VS Codium on WSL

  - `wget -qO - https://gitlab.com/paulcarroty/vscodium-deb-rpm-repo/raw/master/pub.gpg | gpg --dearmor | sudo dd of=/usr/share/keyrings/vscodium-archive-keyring.gpg`
  - `echo 'deb [ signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/vscodium-archive-keyring.gpg ] https://download.vscodium.com/debs vscodium main' | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscodium.list`
  - `sudo apt update && sudo apt install codium`
- Remove the WSL warning nag

  - `echo -e >> ~/.bashrc "\nexport GDK_SCALE=2\nalias codium='DONT_PROMPT_WSL_INSTALL=1 codium'"`
  - `source ~/.bashrc`
- Set Fractional Scaling Support (in Windows) - https://github.com/microsoft/wslg/issues/23

  - Create File: `%UserProfile%\.wslgconfig`
  - Add:

```
[system-distro-env]
WESTON_RDP_DEBUG_DESKTOP_SCALING_FACTOR=100
```

- Zoom out twice in VSCodium (Ctrl-)

Then in Windows, create a shortcut and in the target field add:

`C:\Windows\System32\wsl.exe bash -c "export GDK_SCALE=2 && DONT_PROMPT_WSL_INSTALL=1 codium"`

This will launch the WSL version directly.

**Pros:**

- Can store files fully within Linux to get proper file watching support
- IDE intellisense works *(even in Go)*

**Cons:**

- It's a bit slower than native Windows
- Fractional scaling of WSLg apps is not yet supported, so the standard 150% Windows scaling for 4k screens won't work and you need to adjust font sizes and put up with an oversized / undersized menu bar.